# If condition in html.erb rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I place an if condition in the HTML, in pseudocode, I'd like to achieve the following:

```
if @time.status is pending
  place edit and delete below the message
else
  not just display
end
```

This is my current code:

```
<% @value.each do |s| %>
  <p><strong>Message:</strong>
    <%= s.message %>
  </p>
  <p><strong>Date</strong>
    <%= s.date  %>
  </p>
  <p><strong>Status:</strong>
    <%= s.status %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', value(), %>
    <%= link_to 'Delete', value(),  %>
  </p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to @time and status is an attribute of it, with a value that can be "pending" (thing you didn't add in the question), then you can do:

```
<% if @time.status == 'pending' %>
  <!-- place edit and delete -->
<% else %>
  <% @value.each do |s| %>
    <p>
      <strong>Message:</strong>
      <%= s.message %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Date</strong>
      <%= s.date  %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Status:</strong>
      <%= s.status %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= link_to 'Edit', value(), %>
      <%= link_to 'Delete', value(),  %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is same as your iteration

```
 <% if @time.status=="PENDING" %>
  #your html code for edit in delete
 <%end%>
```